# accessing shared resource independently in PHP is possible or its better to use JAVA's synchronization mechanism?

Tags: java, php

i am developing a website in PHP , in which a single resource would be viewed by multiple users at the same time.i want to prevent other users from viewing or buying the same resource which some other user is about to buy.That is , i want to lock the resource and provide synchronized access to it.Is is possible to develop this thing in PHP or i have to use java's threading and synchronization concept and integrate it with php via xml.??please tell me whether i am on a right track?

i have read about:
'bool sem_acquire ( resource $sem_identifier )'
 available in php and also about

```
<?php

$fp = fopen("/tmp/lock.txt", "r+");

if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) {  // acquire an exclusive lock
    ftruncate($fp, 0);      // truncate file
    fwrite($fp, "Write something here\n");
    fflush($fp);            // flush output before releasing the lock
    flock($fp, LOCK_UN);    // release the lock
} else {
    echo "Couldn't get the lock!";
}

fclose($fp);

?>
```

But i am not sure that will it work flawless or not.
please help.
regards
om

Comment: You should use the native tools available in whatever you're developing in. I'm not familiar enough with PHP to specify how to do it, but it doesn't make any sense at all to run a separate system just to handle synchronization, and resource contention is a standard issue that has to be addressed by any language.

Comment: What about database transactions?

Comment: what resources are we talking about? Can it be handled by database? Does it really need to be a file?

Comment: @IvanHušnjak suppose the resource is a unique pen-drive and its availability details are fetched dynamically from DB. can i know how to handle this using database transactions.

Answer (score 0):

Better manage that via the **database**.

```
UPDATE offers SET buyer = ? WHERE id = ? AND buyer IS NULL
```

And then check the result of course.